# ANDROID: open an URL in external browser, while continuing the application

Tags: android

In the starting activity of my app I show a dialog to user and ask if he wants to see some contents in my website or not.

If he clicks No, the dialog disappears and I call continueActivity() to do some process and go from current activity to MainActivity.
If he click yes, I want to open the webpage in the external browser and again I call continueActivity() to do some process and go from current activity to MainActivity.

The problem is in positive state. This is my code in positive state:

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.aaa.ir"));
startActivity(browserIntent);
continueActivity();
```

Because of calling continueActivity(), the external browser can't open and if I don't call continueActivity(), the URL opens in the external browser and the app sticks in the current activity.

So how could I open the URL and at the same time, continue the process and go to other activities.

Comment: You can use startActivityForResult .

Comment: I agree with @keshav.

Comment: try calling continueActivity() before browser intent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually use

```
startActivityForResult(browserIntent, BROWSER_REQUEST);
```

and override **onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultStat, Intent intent)**

```
if(reqCode == BROWSER_REQUEST) {
    continueActivity();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you call startActivity, your current Activity will follow through the exit of the Activity lifecycle. This is unavoidable.

If you have processing you want to continue in the meantime, you should consider a Service. If you want the App to return to its current state, you need to store relevant data and load your Activity to its previous state (or next intended state).

Answer (score 0):

in both ways ContinueActivity is opening. i don't know you architecture. You could just add to intent some extra like

```
intent.putBoolean("openExternalLink", dialogResultHere);
```

Then in continueActivity you will got this intent like

```
getIntent().getBoolean("openExternalLink")
```

also dont forget to delete this option, otherwise you will open browser each time after Activity recreation (screen rotation, minimize, etc.)

getIntent().removeBoolean("openExternalLink");

P.S. signatures of methods could be littlebit different, but general idea is here